# CurrentValues.SetValues(); is not working on nullable property

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I would like to patch a nullable Int32 value from null to a concrete value it throws "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'."

Although when I patch it from a concrete value to null it works perfectly.
The Int64 is the key, the int is the nullable property.

The model:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public Int64 Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

The patch method:

```
public async Task ApplyPatchAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entityName, 
       List<PatchDto> patchDtos) where TEntity : class
       {
           var nameValuePairProperties = patchDtos.ToDictionary(a => 
           a.PropertyName, a => a.PropertyValue);

           var dbEntityEntry = context.Entry(entityName);
           dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(nameValuePairProperties);
           dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
           await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class PatchDto
   {
       public string PropertyName { get; set; }
       public object PropertyValue { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to set ID or Age?  Age is nullable because it is defined as int?  Id does not have a question mark.  The error is indicating casting an int32 to an int64.

Comment: Don't store the age of someone, store their date of birth and calculate their age; unless your expecting your users to not age they are registered in the application?

Comment: I am trying to set the Age that is Nullable<int>. The identifier cannot be modified, and it is not given among the List<PatchDto> patchDtos.

Comment: I am using a simplified example. Age is only an example variable.